# Dynamic Programming and legendre transformation?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, algorithms

I read once (I can't find it anymore:( ), that the [Legendre transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation) from the Lagrange formalism to the Hamilton formalism can be seen as [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

I have never seen it like this and I was wondering if this statement is correct and if so, why?

Comment: Is it possible you were thinking of linear programming (or non-linear programming) instead of dynamic programming -- in other words, constrained optimization problems? If so, there is work applying the Legendre transform to these kinds of problems, here is a random reference: https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1989-314-02/S0002-9947-1989-1005526-8/S0002-9947-1989-1005526-8.pdf

Comment: Also possibly of interest: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4330459/

Comment: FWIW, to Legendre transform one has to find a supremum, which can be done via a suitable programming algorithm.